# Why .exe from python does't open any prompt, but .py directly runs fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just finished a small project on python, running through pycharm works, also used pyinstaller and ran ok on linux, but when I tried compiling with pyinstaller on windows wheneer I open the exe file, it just doesn't do anything (should be running some functions that ask for user input).

EDIT 1: As pointed out in the comments by @alexis, I've tried writing another program, single file, with some prints and two outputs but again no luck :(

Here's the newer one:

```
print('Test win exe')
response = input('Did you find this useful?')
if response=="yes":
    print('Glad I could help!! :)')
else:
    print('Then GTH!')
input("Exit")
```

Code on 'main' file:

```
import support_functions
import menus
caixa = menus.main_menu()
if input('Salvar fechamento de caixa? [s/n]')=="s":
    support_functions.save_file(caixa.pop(0), caixa)
```

Code on support_functions

```
from datetime import date
def convert_and_replace(number):
    number = number.replace(",", ".")
    number = float(number)
    return number
def save_file(turno, lista):
    filename = 'T' + str(turno) + str(date.today()) + '.txt'
    file = open(filename, "x")
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        file.write(str(lista[i]))
        file.write("\r\n")
    file.close()
```

Code on 'menus'

```
import support_functions


def main_menu():
    print('Fechamento de Caixa')
    numero = input('Numero: ')
    dados = [numero]
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_a())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_b())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_c())
    print('(D) Cartões')
    print(' (D-a) POS')
    dados = dados.__add__(['(D) Cartões', '(D-a) POS'])
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_d_a_a())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_d_a_b())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_d_a_c())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_d_a_d())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_e())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_f())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_g())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_h())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_i())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_j())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_k())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_l())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_m())
    dados = dados.__add__(menu_n())
    return dados


def menu_a():
    a = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(A) Valor em Dinheiro: R$'))
    return ['(A) Valor em Dinheiro', a]


def menu_b():
    b = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(B) Valor total de Sangrias: R$'))
    return ['(B) Valor total de Sangrias', b]


def menu_c():
    print('(C) Cheques')
    c_a = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('  (C-a) Valor de Cheques à Vista: R$'))
    c_b = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('  (C-b) Valor de Cheques à Prazo: R$'))
    c = c_a + c_b
    return ['(C) Cheques', '(C-a) Valor de Cheques à Vista', c_a, '(C-b) Valor de Cheques à Prazo', c_b,
            '# Total (C)', c]


def menu_d_a_a():
    print('     (D-a-a) Crédito')
    visa_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Visa: R$'))
    mastercard_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Mastercard: R$'))
    elo_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('            Elo: R$'))
    banricompras_30 = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Banricompras 30 Dias: R$'))
    banricompras_45 = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Banricompras 45 Dias: R$'))
    banricompras_60 = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Banricompras 60 Dias: R$'))
    banricompras_90 = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Banricompras 90 Dias: R$'))
    amex = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          American Express: R$'))
    cabal_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Cabal: R$'))
    # diners_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Diners: R$'))
    hiper_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Hipercard: R$'))
    verdecard_cr = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Verdecard: R$'))
    #  Totalizador Credito
    d_a_a = visa_cr + mastercard_cr + elo_cr + banricompras_30 + banricompras_45 + banricompras_60 + banricompras_90 \
        + cabal_cr + amex + hiper_cr + verdecard_cr
    return ['(D-a-a) Crédito', 'Visa', visa_cr, 'Mastercard', mastercard_cr, 'Elo', elo_cr, 'Banricompras 30 Dias',
            banricompras_30, 'Banricompras 45 Dias', banricompras_45, 'Banricompras 60 Dias', banricompras_60,
            'Banricompras 90 Dias', banricompras_90, 'American Express', amex, 'Cabal', cabal_cr,  'Hipercard',
            hiper_cr, 'Verdecard', verdecard_cr, '# Total (D-a-a)', d_a_a]


def menu_d_a_b():
    print('     (D-a-b) Débito')
    banricompras_db = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Banricompras: R$'))
    cabal_db = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Cabal: R$'))
    elo_db = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('            Elo: R$'))
    mastercard_db = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Mastercard: R$'))
    visa_db = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Visa: R$'))
    # Totalizador Debito
    d_a_b = banricompras_db + cabal_db + elo_db + mastercard_db + visa_db
    return ['(D-a-b) Débito', 'Banricompras', banricompras_db, 'Cabal', cabal_db, 'Elo', elo_db, 'Mastercard',
            mastercard_db, 'Visa', visa_db, '# Total (D-a-b)', d_a_b]


def menu_d_a_c():
    print('     (D-a-c) Parcelados')
    elo_pc = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('            Elo: R$'))
    hiper_pc = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Hipercard: R$'))
    mastercard_pc = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Mastercard: R$'))
    verdecard_pc = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Verdecard: R$'))
    visa_pc = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('           Visa: R$'))
    # Totalizador Parcelado
    d_a_c = elo_pc + hiper_pc + mastercard_pc + verdecard_pc + visa_pc
    return ['(D-a-c) Parcelados', 'Elo', elo_pc, 'Hipercard', hiper_pc, 'Mastercard', mastercard_pc, 'Verdecard',
            verdecard_pc, 'Visa', visa_pc, '# Total (D-a-c)', d_a_c]


def menu_d_a_d():
    print('     (D-a-d) Vale/Beneficio')
    alelo_al = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Alelo Alimentação: R$'))
    alelo_rf = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Alelo Refeição: R$'))
    banricard_al = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Banricard Alimentação: R$'))
    banricard_cb = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Banricard Combustivel: R$'))
    sodexo_al = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Sodexo Alimentação: R$'))
    sodexo_cb = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Sodexo Combustivel: R$'))
    vr_al = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         VR Alimentação: R$'))
    vr_bn = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         VR Beneficio: R$'))
    vr_cb = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         VR Combustivel: R$'))
    vr_rf = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         VR Refeição: R$'))
    ticket_al = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Ticket Alimentação: R$'))
    ticket_rt = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('         Ticket Restaurante: R$'))
    shell_rf = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('          Shell Resgate Fácil: R$'))
    # Totalizador Vale/Beneficio
    d_a_d = alelo_al + alelo_rf + banricard_al + banricard_cb + sodexo_al + sodexo_cb + vr_al + vr_bn + vr_cb + vr_rf + ticket_al + ticket_rt + shell_rf
    return ['(D-a-d) Vale/Beneficio', 'Alelo Alimentação', alelo_al, 'Alelo Refeição', alelo_rf,
            'Banricard Alimentação', banricard_al, 'Banricard Combustivel', banricard_cb, 'Sodexo Alimentação',
            sodexo_al, 'Sodexo Combustivel', sodexo_cb, 'VR Alimentação', vr_al, 'VR Beneficio', vr_bn,
            'VR Combustivel', vr_cb, 'VR Refeição', vr_rf, 'Ticket Alimentação', ticket_al, 'Ticket Restaurante',
            ticket_rt, 'Shell Resgate Fácil', shell_rf, '# Total (D_a_d', d_a_d]


def menu_e():
    e = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(E) Notas à Prazo: R$'))
    return ['(E) Notas à Prazo', e]


def menu_f():
    f = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(F) Recarga: R$'))
    return ['(F) Recarga', f]


def menu_g():
    g = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(G) Quitação de Notas à Prazo: R$'))
    return ['(G) Quitação de Notas à Prazo', g]


def menu_h():
    h = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(H) Pagamento de Notas Fiscais: R$'))
    return ['(H) Pagamento de Notas Fiscais', h]


def menu_i():
    i: int = input('(I) Leitura Café: ')
    return ['(I) Leitura Café', i]


def menu_j():
    j: int = input('(J) Lanches Entrada: ')
    return ['(J) Lanches Entrada', j]


def menu_k():
    k: int = input('(K) Lanches Saida: ')
    return ['(K) Lanches Saida', k]


def menu_l():
    l = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(L) Vales Troco Recebidos: R$'))
    return ['(L) Vales Troco Recebidos', l]


def menu_m():
    m = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(M) Vales Troco Emitidos: R$'))
    return ['(M) Vales Troco Emitidos', m]


def menu_n():
    n = support_functions.convert_and_replace(input('(N) Troco Final: R$'))
    return ['(N) Troco Final', n]
```

Is there something I'm missing, because it really doesn't make sense since the linux executable worked fine?

Comment: .exe is native to Windows, but on linux, executables run differently. Maybe create a win version and linux version.

Comment: Considering this is a CLI application (no GUI), have you tried opening a CMD, navigating to that folder and running the exe from there?

Comment: @BogdanCondurache yes, it doesn't even output anything

Comment: @SurajKothari not sure what you meant, but if what you're saying is recompile on a windows pc, yes it's what i've done to get the exe I was talking about

Comment: Here's what you should try next: Write a 5-line program that prints a line of output and asks for user input, like yours does. See if you can reproduce the problem, and post _that_ in your question instead of your full code. The odds that someone here can help you will be astronomically greater.

Comment: Agreed, if you don't have any IO, you need to work on writing "hello world" and deal with your exe builder on windows. It's not a python question.